Symplectic form on the space of geodesic currents on a surface?
There are well-known symplectic forms on the  Teichmuller space $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma)$ of a closed surface $\Sigma$ (Wolpert gave a formula in Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates) and the space of measured geodesic laminations (Thurston symplectic form on $\mathcal{ML}(\Sigma)$) which are mapping class group equivariant. Teichmuller space $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma)$ and $\mathcal{ML}(\Sigma)$ both embed in the space of geodesic currents $\mathcal{C}(\Sigma)$. Moreover, if $\tilde{\Sigma}\to \Sigma$ is a finite-sheeted regular cover, then there exists a projection from $\mathcal{T}(\tilde{\Sigma}) \to \mathcal{C}(\tilde{\Sigma})\to \mathcal{C}(\Sigma)$ and $\mathcal{ML}(\tilde{\Sigma})\to \mathcal{C}(\tilde{\Sigma})\to \mathcal{C}(\Sigma)$ since $\mathcal{C}(\Sigma)$ is convex, so one may average and project (a kind of transfer map). The symplectic forms should be compatible with respect to covers, up to scaling.
I’m wondering whether there is a common generalization of these symplectic forms to the space of geodesic currents, ie a symplectic form whose restriction to these subspaces gives the corresponding form, maybe up to rescaling? The space of geodesic currents $\mathcal{C}(\Sigma)$ embeds in $\mathcal{C}_{\pm}(\Sigma)$, signed measures on the space of geodesics, and hence has a natural linear structure ($\mathcal{C}(\Sigma)$ is convex, but might not have a tangent space at boundary points). Since $\mathcal{C}(\Sigma)$ is infinite dimensional, I’m just asking for a non-degenerate, antisymmetric pairing on the tangent space, equivariant with respect to the mapping class group action, and maybe a closed 2-form if one may make sense of that.
